# Error when validate form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a trouble when I using Jquery validate the value get from the form.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
     var err = [];
     var form = $(this).attr('id');
     switch(form){
          case 'formmecard':
               var hasError = 3;
            if($('#me-name').val() == ''){
                err[0] = 'Please input your full name';
            }else{
                if(!nameReg.test($('#me-name').val())){
                    err[0] = 'Your name has only contain characters';
                }else{
                    hasError--;
                }
            }
            if($('#me-email').val() == ''){
                err[1] = 'Please input your email address';
            }else{
                if(!emailReg.test($('#me-email').val())){
                    err[1] = 'Invalid email address';
                }else{
                    hasError--;
                }
            }
            if($('#me-phone').val() == ''){
                err[2] = 'Please input your phone number';
            }else{
                if(!numberReg.test($('#me-phone').val())){
                    err[2] = 'The phone number is invalid';
                }else{
                    hasError--;
                }
            }

            if(hasError != 0){
                for(var i=0;i<err.length;i++){
                    switch(i){
                        case 0:
                            $('.checkname').html(err[0]).fadeIn(1000,function(){
                                $(this).fadeOut(1000);
                            });
                            $('#me-name').focus();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            $('.checkemail').html(err[1]).fadeIn(1000,function(){
                                $(this).fadeOut(1000);
                            });
                            $('#me-email').focus();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            $('.checkphone').html(err[2]).fadeIn(1000,function(){
                                $(this).fadeOut(1000);
                            });
                            $('#me-phone').focus();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                err = [];
            }else{
                var website = $('#me-url').val();
                if(website != ''){
                    if(!website.match(urlReg))
                        $('#me-url').val('http://' + website);
                }
                var content = $(this).serialize();
                var action = $(this).attr('action');
                callajax(action,content);
            }
            break;
          default:
            break;
     }
  return false;
});
```

When I test that function its build not any problem. But when I add a case to function its has been error

```
case 'formvcard':
            var hasError = 3;
            var name = $('#v-name').val();
            if(name == ''){
                err[0] = 'Please input your full name';
            }else{
                if(!nameReg.test(name)){
                    err[0] = 'Your name has only contain characters';
                }else{
                    hasError--;
                }
            }
            var email = $('#v-email').val();
            if(email == ''){
                err[1] = 'Please input your email address';
            }else{
                if(!emailReg.test($(email)){
                    err[1] = 'Invalid email address';
                }else{
                    hasError--;
                }
            }
            var phone = $('#v-phone').val();
            if(phone == ''){
                err[2] = 'Please input your phone number';
            }else{
                if(!numberReg.test(phone)){
                    err[2] = 'The phone number is invalid';
                }else{
                    hasError--;
                }
            }

            if(hasError != 0){
                for(var i=0;i<err.length;i++){
                    switch(i){
                        case 0:
                            $('.checkname').html(err[0]).fadeIn(1000,function(){
                                $(this).fadeOut(1000);
                            });
                            $('#v-name').focus();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            $('.checkemail').html(err[1]).fadeIn(1000,function(){
                                $(this).fadeOut(1000);
                            });
                            $('#v-email').focus();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            $('.checkphone').html(err[2]).fadeIn(1000,function(){
                                $(this).fadeOut(1000);
                            });
                            $('#v-phone').focus();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                err = [];
            }else{
                var website = $('#v-url').val();
                if(website != ''){
                    if(!website.match(urlReg))
                        $('#v-url').val('http://' + website);
                }
                var content = $(this).serialize();
                var action = $(this).attr('action');
                callajax(action,content);
            }
            break;
```

I using method post to submit data to server but when I add that case to my function, it has appeared error when it using method get to submit data. Help me solve my problem, please.

Comment: what's the error? better to use jquery validation plugin

Comment: What is the error, exactly?

Comment: It's not use method post to submit data so that it is automatically use method get to submit data. That is my trouble. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to do it in some other way?, like having a submit button and listen for the click event and use a preventdefault method, so you can validate your form before you do the submit at that form

```
$("#buton").click(function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();

  /*
    your validations here
  */

  //to finalize

  $("#yourform").submit();
});
```